# How to return an Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to descentralize my form validators by having generalized functions that may work with any form. In some cases, I use an Ajax Call to make the validation in the server and then send the results back to Javascript. But I can't send the data back to the function as an object.
Consider the example:

```
function isValidEmail(email){ var result = ajaxCallFunction(email);
   if (result.valid == true){
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
};

function ajaxCallFunction(email){
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "validateEmail.php",
        data: {'email': email},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            return response;
        }
    });
}
```

|||| PHP - validateEmail.php ||||

Performs email validation and existance check in the database and return a
json object with the attributes 'valid' (true/false) and 'exists' (true/false);

The problem is with the return I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined", even though validateEmail.php always send an Object with that attribute.
It might be some misunderstanding of javascript objects, but I can't figure out how it realy works.

Some explanation on that would be satiscatory, as well as some advice in the data model I'm using.

Comment: `ajaxCallFunction()` is not returning anything. `return response` from the `success` function won't make `ajaxCallFunction` return that value.

Comment: it will always return a undefined value, as it is a async Ajax call.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)